# Retrieve data from table using stored procedure PostgreSQL 11.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have the table with two columns `cola` and `colb`.

I want to do select columns from table using stored procedure.

Note: I don't want to use function because of return type.

Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sptest()
LANGUAGE sql

AS $BODY$
         select cola from test;
$BODY$;
```

Calling procedure:

```
call sptest()
```

Output:

Nothing in the data output.

Message window shows:

```
CALL

Query returned successfully in 147 msec.
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have different `SELECT` statements depends on the input parameters and I don't want use function because of need to specify the return type which will dynamic in my case.

Comment: You can define the function as `returns setof record`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, But you need to give column definition list for `setof record`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a refcursor as an inout parameter to be able to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sptest(result_data inout refcursor)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  open result_data for select cola from test;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Then call it like this:

```
call sptest('data');
```

The parameter passed is the name of the refcursor returned.

Whether or not the result is displayed depends on the SQL client you are using.

In `psql` you would need to do something like this:

```
begin; -- not required if you turned off autocommit
call sptest('data');
fetch all in "data";
commit;
```

Some SQL clients will do that automatically for you.